# Query two tables and select data where two fields match

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in a database, one called livestock, the other description.

```
Table: livestock
|    id     |      name         |     scientific        |
   (eg 1)      (eg Tree Frog)     (eg hyla marmorata)

Table 2: info
|  scientific     |     description      |
  hyla marmorata     description of h.m
```

I have a dynamic page that pulls everything from `livestock` for a certain `id`

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `livestock` WHERE `id` = ' . (int) $_GET['id'];
```

This all works fine, but i need to get the `description` from the `info` table for this record, but cant match an id. The reason being that there will be rows in the `info` table that wont be in the `livestock` table and id's wouldn't be the same each time i update the livestock table as some animals will not be in stock and i don't want to update the `description` every time i update the `livestock` table. The `scientific` field will however always be the same for the desired records.

I have tried the following but it didnt work...

```
$query =   "SELECT info.description, info.scientific, livestock.scientific ".
        "FROM info, livestock ".
        "WHERE info.scientific = livestock.scientific ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($con));  

        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

        echo $row2['info.description'];
```

Both `scientific` fields are Varchar(100). Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Define 'didn't work'.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal it is usually considered as a good practice to use [surrogate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) ("id") to identifies rows in your table. Nevertheless, it is perfectly acceptable to use [natural keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) as the OP wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `left outer join`.  This will keep all rows in the `livestock` table, even those that do not match the `info` table:

```
     SELECT i.description, i.scientific, l.scientific
     FROM livestock l left outer join
          info i
          on i.scientific = l.scientific
     WHERE l.id = ' . (int) $_GET['id'];
```

I'm not sure why you are pulling `scientific` from both tables.  The query already has the condition that they are equal.  You should just be using `l.scientific`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this works perfectly! I've tried so many different things. Hero